# I am trying to import images and it is returning "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

Tags: python, opencv, python-os

I am giving a folder path to my function but it is returning TypeError

```
faces, labels = prepare_training_data("C:\\Users\\prite\\Desktop\\projects\\0007\\training-data")
```

the error it shows is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c070ed2f52c1> in <module>
----> 1 faces, labels = prepare_training_data("C:\\Users\\prite\\Desktop\\projects\\0007\\training-data")
      2 print("Total faces: ", len(faces))
      3 print("Total labels: ", len(labels))

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

My function is:

```
def prepare_training_data(data_folder_path):
    dirs = os.listdir(data_folder_path)
    faces = []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add "r" before path.

prepare_training_data(r'C:\Users\prite\Desktop\projects\0007\training-data')

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from prepare_training_data function, which means that you are returning "None" type object (which is of course non-iterable). Therefore

To fix, you need to add a return statement to your function

```
def prepare_training_data(data_folder_path):
    dirs = os.listdir(data_folder_path)
    faces = []
    labels = [] 
    return faces, labels
```

Comment: I have added the return statement in the following lines after completing my function.